# Ck-editor i had added ck-editor with div contenteditable="true" when i scroll the page it is floting up and down.how to fix it on the top of div

Tags: ckeditor

How to fix ck-editor on the top of content editable="true" div and fix the width of the ck editor.ck-editor floating up and down side of the div.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search in ckeditor.js [ case "bottom":f("absolute","top" ] and replace  third parameter of the function with [ b.y-n-o  ]  its done.